# Dual Boot Fedora 23 and windows 10..windows 10 not booting

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, fedora, grub

I am a newbie and recently installed fedora 23 on my windows 10 through partition. 
After installing fedora 23, I get 3 options in the menu to select the Os i want to boot. 2 options for Fedora 23 and 1 option for windows 7..??( I had windows 10 installed on my computer). Fedora 23 works fine but windows 10 doesnt boot up. It seems that the computer can't locate where to boot windows 10 from..
Any help would be appreciated. I have been trying this for 3 days now!!!
This is the o/p that I get after sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D22243C5-A432-4A14-8718-29015B4F7782
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     923648   1126399    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1126400   1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1159168 315260927 314101760 149.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  315260928 315262975      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda6  315262976 316286975   1024000   500M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  316286976 468860927 152573952  72.8G Linux LVM
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8fd842a8
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848 204799999 204593152  97.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       204800000 614399999 409600000 195.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       614400000 976771071 362371072 172.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 44 GiB, 47202697216 bytes, 92192768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.3 GiB, 7868514304 bytes, 15368192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 21.5 GiB, 23043506176 bytes, 45006848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: "[I] recently installed fedora 23 on my windows 10 through partition" - how did you do that? I see you have some 200+GB of free space on the first disk. Were you shrinking partitions, or using Fedora installer? If Fedora created non-bootable system it is a bug - boot into Fedora, create a new bug against Anaconda component, and attach everything in /var/log/anaconda as attachments to that bug.

Answer (score 0):

So it got solved..
Apparantly I had used USB universal installer to make the image for fedora23 and it got booted in Legacy mode. Windows 10 is in uefi, so the two OS were conflicting with each other. Formatted Linux, and made the image with the softwares recommended in the link here:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Installation_Guide/
And voila..problem solved..can boot windows and fedora now!!

Comment: In the vein of Stack Exchange, would you mind putting more details about _what_ you had to change to get it to work?